# Display a lightning:icon inside lightning:input

Tags: lightning

Please let me know how can I embed a `lightning:icon` inside a `lightning:input` tag.

I am using the below code :

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left">
    <lightning:icon iconName="action:add_contact" size="small" alternativeText="Add Contact"/>
    <lightning:input label="Account Search" name="accountsearch"  type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you only have to use lightning:input component? If not, then refer the link below:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input

Comment: you simply need to place your input and icon under same div element where this div will hold the class "slds-grid" => this will make them align as grid row elements.

Answer (score 6):

The Lightning Design System docs have a lot of good information regarding your different options for [displaying icons within HTML inputs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input).

Here's an example where you have an icon left of the input if you just copy/paste from the docs:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Input Label</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left">
        <svg class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_left slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search" />
        </svg>
        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1" class="slds-input" placeholder="Placeholder Text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

If you are using within a Salesforce Lightning app, you need to used a Lightning icon component instead of the HTML-centric SVG tag. It should look like this:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Input Label</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left">
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:search" size="x-small" title="" />
        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1" class="slds-input" placeholder="Placeholder Text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Although it's a bit more work that just going with `<lightning:input type="search" label="Search" name="search" />`, you'll have complete control over the icon versus relying on Salesforce to determine the icon based on the component's `type` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a easy way of doing this for a solution I was working on, so I went ahead and created a custom component that basically does what gotoplanb suggests by creating a wrapper around a series of divs for the lightning:icon and lightning:input base components. As a bonus, I needed to be able to display a lightning:helptext inline label, so the component does that. I posted the code in a public GIT repository at https://github.com/scVandal/sfsCompoundLabelInput. Might be a good place to start and expand on.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using the pure CSS.

Your div is going to be the size of the child lightning-input. Giving the div **"position:relative"**, while giving the icon **"position:absolute"** will allow to set dynamic position for the icon within the parent's space. Z-index is required to make the icon overlap the input.

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <lightning-input ...(other required attributes)></lightning-input> 

    <lightning-button-icon 
        style="position: absolute; right: 1%; top: 50%; z-index: 10;" ...(other required attributes)>
    </lightning-button-icon>
</div>
```

[image]